# Improve connection speed for South America users to server in Europe

Tags: tcp, ovh

I'm running an MMORPG Game with central server based in Europe-Warsaw hosted on OVH.
My player base is located both in Europe (mostly Poland) and South America (mostly Brazil).
Due to server localization Europe players have very good Ping response time at around 40ms, but at the same time I'd like to be able to provide at least decent experience for the other half of my players. Iideally I'd like to achieve Ping at around 100-200ms, currently SA players report that the ping can reach up to 600ms which is considered unplayable.

I've read that routing traffic through the US may help, but after renting a cheap server in Miami and routing SA players TCP connection though Nginx located on that server players reported that nothing really changed in terms of their connection quality.

I'm looking for an advice on servers or server providers that used as a proxy would noticeably improve TCP connection quality between South America (Brazil, regular users) and Europe (Poland, OVH datacenter) for ~200 active users and ideally would not cost me more than 40$/mo.

Comment: `ping can reach up to 600ms` That is just a terrible Internet connection. Most providers publish SLA's for their services. 200ms is about average max for a trip halfway around the world. There are certainly people in your location that have these services, then repackage and resell them at slower speeds and higher prices.

Answer (score 2):

> renting a cheap server in Miami ... TCP connection though Nginx located on that server players reported that nothing really changed in terms of their connection quality.

A proxy adds additional latency since every data needs to be read by the OS kernel, given to the proxy (user space), processed by the proxy, send back to the OS kernel and then send to the final destination. And if you rent a cheap proxy it will likely not have the best connectivity either.

> I'd like to achieve Ping at around 100-200ms

Direct destination between Brasilia and Warsaw is about 10.000km which results in a one-way latency of about 70ms just because how fast data can travel over fiber - no network equipment involved yet. So minimal ping is about 140ms, realistic values are more than 200ms with optimal connectivity - see also https://wondernetwork.com/pings

And to get these values both client and server need to have optimal connectivity to fast trans-continental networks. While you have control over the server you don't have any control over the connectivity of the client.